# Directive inside the dynamically created elements not working with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to change a text to input['type="text"] element with a button appended for updating it. However, when i attach a function($scope.commit_update) on its ng-click event,the function is not firing.

```
$scope.commit_update = function(id){
      console.log(id);
}
$scope.update = function($service_id){

    var current_text = document.getElementById($service_id).innerHTML;
    if(/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(current_text) == false){
        var vars = $service_id.split('-');
        var node = '<div class="input-group" style="width:200px;"><span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="commit_update('+vars[1]+')">Save</span><input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+current_text+'" style="width:200px;"></div>';   
        document.getElementById($service_id).innerHTML = node;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post HTML + directive or u post Fiddle/Plunker. Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jT2Rw/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its not good idea to do any manipulations with DOM in controller. Use `directive` for that.

Angular doesn't know about dynamic HTML you try to append. To make `ng-click` to work we need to *compile* dynamic HTML  source by using `$compile` service.

Here is your modified Fiddle:

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/600/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="service-1" fess>Test</td>
                <td> <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="update()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**JS**

```
fessmodule.directive('fess', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.heyFess = function () {
                console.log('k');
                var current_text = document.getElementById("service-1").innerHTML;
                if (/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(current_text) == false) {

                    var node = '<div class="input-group" style="width:200px;" ><span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click=alertMe()>Save</span><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + current_text + '" style="width:200px;"></input></div>';

                    var e = angular.element(node);
                    $compile(e.contents())(scope);
                    elm.replaceWith(e);
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```